# Realm Suddenly started generating compile errors in a code that was working with no problem _ClassNameRealmProxy

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, realm

I'm creating a very simple project (first time using kotlin), My project was working perfectly however after I moved my kotlin classes from test to main, Realm started to generate lots of errors, now its 2 days I'm struggling with it with no luck.

I tried using Realm 6.0.2 instead of Beta 7.0.0 and same errors.

I created a new project I added only realm and created the two `RealmObject` classes (without touching anything else in the default project) and I'm still getting the same error. I'm really getting crazy at this point. what I don't really understans why does realm put `.` before class names, class names can not start with `.`

There are lots of quesions and answers about the error `illegal start of type pulbic class...` and all were suggesting that they have some code directly inside a class and not in a method and when I have look at their questions that was the case for all of them, but that is not the case with me. This is a brand new project that I have added only the 2 classes.

here is the my classes (the only thing I have added to the project):

```
@RealmClass
open class Deck  (
    @PrimaryKey
    var Id: Int = 0,
    var Name: String = "",
    var _name: String = "",
    var Color: Int = 0,
    var Cards: RealmList<Card> = RealmList()
): RealmObject()

@RealmClass
open class Card  (
    @PrimaryKey
    open var Id: Int = 0,
    open var FrontText: String = "",
    open var BackText: String = "",
    open var Image: String = "",
    open var Correct: Int = 0,
    open var Incorrect: Int = 0
): RealmObject()
```

And here is the error:
[image]

> C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:37: error: illegal start of type
>   public class _CardRealmProxy extends .Card
>                                        ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:37: error:  expected
>   public class _CardRealmProxy extends .Card
>                                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:38: error:  expected
>       implements RealmObjectProxy, _CardRealmProxyInterface {
>                                  ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:38: error: ';' expected
>       implements RealmObjectProxy, _CardRealmProxyInterface {
>                                                            ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:40: error: illegal start of expression
>       static final class CardColumnInfo extends ColumnInfo {
>       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:85: error: illegal start of expression
>       private static final OsObjectSchemaInfo expectedObjectSchemaInfo = createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo();
>       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:85: error: illegal start of expression
>       private static final OsObjectSchemaInfo expectedObjectSchemaInfo = createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo();
>               ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:85: error: ';' expected
>       private static final OsObjectSchemaInfo expectedObjectSchemaInfo = createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo();
>                     ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:87: error: illegal start of expression
>       private CardColumnInfo columnInfo;
>       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:88: error: illegal start of expression
>       private ProxyState<.Card> proxyState;
>       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:88: error: illegal start of type
>       private ProxyState<.Card> proxyState;
>                          ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:88: error: ';' expected
>       private ProxyState<.Card> proxyState;
>                               ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:88: error: not a statement
>       private ProxyState<.Card> proxyState;
>                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:90: error: ';' expected
>       _CardRealmProxy() {
>                        ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:95: error: ';' expected
>       public void realm$injectObjectContext() {
>                                            ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:101: error: illegal start of type
>           this.proxyState = new ProxyState<.Card>(this);
>                                            ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:101: error: '(' or '[' expected
>           this.proxyState = new ProxyState<.Card>(this);
>                                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:110: error: ';' expected
>       public int realmGet$Id() {
>                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:116: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Id(int value) {
>                              ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:116: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Id(int value) {
>                                        ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:128: error: ';' expected
>       public String realmGet$FrontText() {
>                                       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:134: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$FrontText(String value) {
>                                     ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:134: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$FrontText(String value) {
>                                                  ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:156: error: ';' expected
>       public String realmGet$BackText() {
>                                      ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:162: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$BackText(String value) {
>                                    ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:162: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$BackText(String value) {
>                                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:184: error: ';' expected
>       public String realmGet$Image() {
>                                   ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:190: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Image(String value) {
>                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:190: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Image(String value) {
>                                              ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:212: error: ';' expected
>       public int realmGet$Correct() {
>                                  ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:218: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Correct(int value) {
>                                   ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:218: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Correct(int value) {
>                                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:234: error: ';' expected
>       public int realmGet$Incorrect() {
>                                    ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:240: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Incorrect(int value) {
>                                     ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:240: error: ';' expected
>       public void realmSet$Incorrect(int value) {
>                                               ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:254: error: illegal start of expression
>       private static OsObjectSchemaInfo createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:254: error: illegal start of expression
>       private static OsObjectSchemaInfo createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>               ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:254: error: ';' expected
>       private static OsObjectSchemaInfo createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>                                        ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:254: error: ';' expected
>       private static OsObjectSchemaInfo createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>                                                                         ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:265: error: illegal start of expression
>       public static OsObjectSchemaInfo getExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:265: error: illegal start of expression
>       public static OsObjectSchemaInfo getExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>              ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:265: error: ';' expected
>       public static OsObjectSchemaInfo getExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>                                       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:265: error: ';' expected
>       public static OsObjectSchemaInfo getExpectedObjectSchemaInfo() {
>                                                                     ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:269: error: illegal start of expression
>       public static CardColumnInfo createColumnInfo(OsSchemaInfo schemaInfo) {
>       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:269: error: illegal start of expression
>       public static CardColumnInfo createColumnInfo(OsSchemaInfo schemaInfo) {
>              ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:269: error: ';' expected
>       public static CardColumnInfo createColumnInfo(OsSchemaInfo schemaInfo) {
>                                   ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:269: error: ')' expected
>       public static CardColumnInfo createColumnInfo(OsSchemaInfo schemaInfo) {
>                                                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:269: error: illegal start of expression
>       public static CardColumnInfo createColumnInfo(OsSchemaInfo schemaInfo) {
>                                                                            ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:269: error: ';' expected
>       public static CardColumnInfo createColumnInfo(OsSchemaInfo schemaInfo) {
>                                                                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:282: error: illegal start of type
>       public static .Card createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(Realm realm, JSONObject json, boolean update)
>                     ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:282: error: ';' expected
>       public static .Card createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(Realm realm, JSONObject json, boolean update)
>                      ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:282: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
>       public static .Card createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(Realm realm, JSONObject json, boolean update)
>                           ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:285: error: illegal start of expression
>           .Card obj = null;
>           ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:287: error: illegal start of expression
>               Table table = realm.getTable(.Card.class);
>                                            ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:287: error: ';' expected
>               Table table = realm.getTable(.Card.class);
>                                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:287: error: illegal start of expression
>               Table table = realm.getTable(.Card.class);
>                                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:287: error: ';' expected
>               Table table = realm.getTable(.Card.class);
>                                                  ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:287: error: illegal start of expression
>               Table table = realm.getTable(.Card.class);
>                                                       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:288: error: illegal start of expression
>               CardColumnInfo columnInfo = (CardColumnInfo) realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class);
>                                                                                            ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:288: error: ';' expected
>               CardColumnInfo columnInfo = (CardColumnInfo) realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class);
>                                                                                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:288: error: illegal start of expression
>               CardColumnInfo columnInfo = (CardColumnInfo) realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class);
>                                                                                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:288: error: ';' expected
>               CardColumnInfo columnInfo = (CardColumnInfo) realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class);
>                                                                                                  ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:288: error: illegal start of expression
>               CardColumnInfo columnInfo = (CardColumnInfo) realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class);
>                                                                                                       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: illegal start of expression
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: ')' expected
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                  ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error:  expected
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                       ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: not a statement
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                      ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: illegal start of expression
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                            ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: ';' expected
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                             ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: not a statement
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                               ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: ';' expected
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                                    ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:297: error: ';' expected
>                       objectContext.set(realm, table.getUncheckedRow(rowIndex), realm.getSchema().getColumnInfo(.Card.class), false, Collections. emptyList());
>                                                                                                                                                                      ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                   ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                    ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                        ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                         ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                              ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                               ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                    ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                     ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                          ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:307: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, null, true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                                         ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                   ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                    ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                        ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                         ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: illegal start of expression
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                              ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                    ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                                 ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: not a statement
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                                         ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:309: error: ';' expected
>                       obj = (io.realm._CardRealmProxy) realm.createObjectInternal(.Card.class, json.getInt("Id"), true, excludeFields);
>                                                                                                                                      ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:357: error: illegal start of type
>       public static .Card createUsingJsonStream(Realm realm, JsonReader reader)
>                     ^C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\FlashCards2\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\io\realm_CardRealmProxy.java:357: error: ';' expected
>       public static .Card createUsingJsonStream(Realm realm, JsonReader reader)

Comment: Mobayen Have you fixed the issue ? I am stuck at the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I had not imported the package name (my own application package name) in the entity classes. adding the import solved the problem.